# How do we minimise the timeout when using Google Cloud PubSub Client Library for php?

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

We have been getting these exceptions from Google this evening:

> Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: cURL error 56: OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
>
> Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException(code: 0): cURL error 7: Failed to connect to oauth2.googleapis.com port 443: Connection timed out (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
>
> Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException(code: 0): cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 2001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

We can handle the exceptions fine, but there is a significant timeout between the connection initiation and the exception occurring. This means our server hangs for a long period of time as a request is initiated to Google, waits for connection to be properly created, fails, and then continues. This means our requests take a ridiculous amount of time (~20 seconds - 3 minutes approximately) instead of milliseconds.

So:

- How can we determine what the root cause of this problem is? I'm assuming it's a Google related service issue, but their Google Console is clear
- How can we set a timeout to be significantly shorter so that it doesn't cause long delays, particularly of importance with user facing requests.

We're using the PHP PubSubClient, specifically only the `publish` method at the moment.

Comment: Can you take a look at this (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching) and see if it helps you?

Comment: We're not batching our calls - we're only calling once per request. That does lead me to the API Reference Docs though (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.130.0/pubsub/topic?method=publish), and in turn to https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/v0.130.0/PubSub/src/PubSubClient.php#L133 which defines a requestTimeout. But it says the default is 0 for REST... so why are we hanging still?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be fixed by the following:

```
$pubsub->publish(
    [
        'data'       => $data,
        'attributes' => $attributes,
    ],
    [

        'requestTimeout' => 2 // Set your own value here (in seconds)
    ]
);
```

This seems to be translated into a Guzzle option under the hood.

See `\Google\Cloud\Core\RestTrait::send` for more info